# Pasting without format on terminal

Tags: python, rsa

I'm developing a rsa cipher program and I'm having issues when trying to paste the ciphered cryptogram string into the decoding program input. It is not a matter of implementation (the program works fine) but of pasting format into the python terminal. For example:

I get the following cryptogram after executing the rsa cipher:

```
=ª’Jß°:Ó¼6¾Ó—ƒõVò£ÄÍ«Ø¬D€µ7BãG!QçæÙ“™íñNóOræIÇ

j~
~Ej.{³«Ã2Ó#G    ‰—)¶¦9pÙ¸‰Ÿ9IÈÎEX4~Í~:ËçDxý”ª]!æ%9áèÑ×ô
ýŽ
```

To my surprise, the same happens when pasting inside this SO post form. Those line breaks are not supposed to appear, therefore I guess it could be that some special chars are being interpreted.   What I want is to one-line only string, as it follows (do not pay a attention to the substring "Mesnage cifrado" this is only program a user oriented indication, what it is worth is what follows that substring):

[image]

Note: I've already tried with `' '` string delimiters

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to past binary data into your terminal.  If so, you shouldn't be doing that.  Binary data should pretty much only be stored in files.  Terminals deal with text and not binary. If you want to be able to copy/paste binary data around, you can encode it with Base64.

Comment: You could encode it a layer before sending and decode after sending.  My point is, identify the characters which are causing line breaks (probably `CR`/`LF`), and replace those with something like `[CR]` and `[LF]`.  Then, after sending, replace `[CR]` with the `CR` control character and `[LF]` with the `LF` control character.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj: That won't work. It's likely the data is already corrupted by the time it is printed out, as just the process of converting random bytes to a string in a character set like UTF-8 will corrupt the data. See the previous comment.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk : Yes that makes sense.  It does seem like binary content and for some reason has control characters in it.  Probably not a good idea to convert characters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got it right, but if you want python to take what you literally typed and not to interpret it, maybe you could give raw strings a shot if you haven't already.

This is the default string:

```
s = 'Hi\nHello'
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Hi
Hello
```

This is what you get with raw strings (you just need to put an `r` before the `'`):

```
raw_s = r'\n=ª’Jß°:Ó¼6¾Ó—ƒõVò£ÄÍ«Ø¬D€µ7BãG!QçæÙ“™\níñNóOræIÇj~~Ej.{³«Ã2Ó#G‰)¶\n¦9pÙ¸‰Ÿ9IÈÎEX4~Í~:ËçDxý”ª]\n!æ%9áèÑ×ôýŽ'
print(raw_s)
```

Output:

```
\n=ª’Jß°:Ó¼6¾Ó—ƒõVò£ÄÍ«Ø¬D€µ7BãG!QçæÙ“™\níñNóOræIÇj~~Ej.{³«Ã2Ó#G‰)¶\n¦9pÙ¸‰Ÿ9IÈÎEX4~Í~:ËçDxý”ª]\n!æ%9áèÑ×ôýŽ
```

(ps: Just added some `\n`'s in your original string for the sake of demonstrating that raw strings will not interpret them as line breaks)

Comment: There's a problem with your example: the string your are using `r` on will be the same with or without the `r`.  Try printing it with and without the `r`.  You will get the same results.  The problem is that you are missing the characters that make it become multi-line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LakshyaRaj, just added some line breaks for the sake of the example. But I'm still curious though, is string interpretation the real OP problem? Cuz for me it could also be something related to UTF-8 character encoding and this kid of stuff...

Comment: OPs problem is different, his output is not something he typed in.

Comment: @David: It seems that the OP's problem is about string interpretation because he is saying that he wants it on one line only, and his string is interpreted incorrectly (because of newline characters), so it goes on multiple lines (unlike what he wanted).